# Most efficient way to invoke Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading

As the title states, I want to know the most efficient ways to invoke a lazy loaded object property.  Consider the following class definition:

```
Class MyObject
{
    private _stringList = null;
    public List<string> StringList
    {
        set
        {
            _stringList = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if(_stringList == null)
            {
                _stringList = new List<string>();
                //fill the List with strings from some data source
            }
            return _stringList;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to pre-load StringList with the most in-expensive operation, what whould that be?

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.StringList.ToString(); //?
obj.StringList.Count(); //?
obj.StringList.Equals(null); //?
```

What about:

```
if(obj.StringList == null){}
```

I don't like this method but it seems like it would be less expensive than calling a method on the property.

I'm looking for an answer specific to List as well as a generic `object`.

EDIT: I understand that this is considered a micro optimization but that is not the point of the question.  I'm not asking if you like what I'm suggesting doing here.  I want to know the best way to do this relative to CPU and/or memory usage and some proof that the suggested method is actually better than others.

Comment: You are returning value from setter?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, no that was a typo, it has been corrected.

Comment: Why do you want to load it? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having it lazy load? Perhaps move the code to a Load method and call that if you need it loaded manually.

Comment: Just "get" it... `var z = obj.StringList;`

Comment: I expanded how you "get" a property. Seriously people...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also think that tis kind of optimization is not relevant, but i guess the "best" would be

```
var someVar = obj.StringList;
```

Just invoke the getter. You may get a warning since you have an unused variable, but you can suppress this warning with a pragma...

But as Sergey already mentioned, in that case it does not make sense to implement lazy load...

Comment: I agree that it is mostly irrelevant, but if I'm going to do it I might as well do it elegantly.  IMO, that's not assigning it to a variable, no offense. I guess its more a question of style.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @PrestonS you asked for the most efficient way to do it, not the most elegant... Anyway there's no elegant solution to do this, anybody that look at your code without knowing the inner working will think that's an error and remove it away. If you want to do it elegantly add a method named PreLoad...

Comment: Dirk, Can you demonstrate that this method is more efficient than any other method?  Is it more efficient in CPU usage, memory usage, both or neither?

Comment: I do not think that such a demonstration is required. The getter will be executed in every case. storing the object in an additional local variable someVar, this will cost one pointer additional space in memory at all.
All other solutions, that will call the getter AND after this some method on the returned object, will have more CPU time, and at least  one pointe less in memory.

Answer (score 5):

I believe comparison with null is the less expensive way. But I would not care of such **micro** optimization (if you are loading data from file or database, then all these options is nothing comparing to IO operations). Also if you want to pre-load data, then you don't need lazy-loading. Main point of lazy-loading is to defer data loading until you *really* will need that data.

UPDATE: If you really want to pre-load data for properties, I suggest you to make it in more explicit way. Otherwise other developers will guess why you are comparing properties with null or setting them to local variables which are not used. Create some method in your class which will clearly show your intent:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.Load(); // or Initialize()
```

Comment: The majority of the time the lazy loading is useful.  But I have come across an instance where I would like to eager load all the properties  to minimize the amount of time I have my data source open and I don't want to rewrite a number of classes to support both lazy and eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

This is classic example of lazy loading. Also note that using setter is defeating purpose of your example because if every client can reset your list then every client must take care of the loading - this is not so good

```
Class MyObject
{
    private List<string> _stringList = null;

    public List<string> StringList
    {

        get
        {
            if(_stringList == null)
            {
                _stringList = new List<string>();
                //fill the List with strings from some data source
            }
            return _stringList;
        }
    }
}
```

On another note, if you use `List.Count > 0`, the optimization for this will be Linq `List.Any`